# The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformButton' | showing when using enough_giphy_flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

when using **emoji_picker** and **enough_giphy_flutter** packages, It shows error like this,

```
The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'PlatformButton'

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, 
or defining a method named 'FlatButton'. child: FlatButton( ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think It is because - the latest version of Flutter, Flatbutton is deprecated and uses TextButton.(https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#context)

But, How do I use these packages in the latest version of Flutter?

my code here : used `emoji_picker` package

```
Widget showEmojiPicker() {
    return EmojiPicker(
      rows: 4,
      columns: 7,
      onEmojiSelected: (emoji, category) {
        print(emoji);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your code.

Comment: try to search for alternative package that work on new version of flutter. these package are outedate

Comment: enough_giphy_flutter  this also